# In Rails with Webpacker app, compiled styles appear to load ok (200), but aren't applied

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

Upgrading an existing React project from Rails 4 to 5.1 and loading assets with the new Webpacker `pack_tag` system. Things seem to compile correctly, I've got a pack file `packs/mutts.jsx` and in my index.html.erb I reference with

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'mutts' %>
 <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'mutts' %>`

When the server runs, this results in 4 files compiled to `app/public/packs/`: a `.js`, `.js.map`, `.css` and `.css.map` - all with [packname]-[hash].extension format.

When I inspect the html generated from the `pack_tag`s, I can see they each link to the corresponding js and css files, with the correct hash in the filename. And looking at the Network tab in devtools, both files load successfully with 200.

But when I look at the Sources tab, I see at `localhost:3000` there is a `packs/` directory that only contains the js file, and the css is nowhere in sight, and styles are definitely not being applied to the page.

Am I getting the file structure or importing wrong or something? Doesn't seem to be a webpack config issue, as the contents of the compiled file look correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where I placed the `stylesheet_pack_tag`. After placing it in the `<head>` it worked.

Should have caught this - most of the demos for Webpacker have the tag placed right with the relevant `javascript_pack_tag`, but in my case I'm rendering a new JS root per page, so the js pack is rendered by a rails view that's not the root application.html.erb

I've seen some webpacker examples that seemed to be going for "keep assets in proximity of concerned code", but I'm happy just chucking global styles in the head here.